# Pass data from ViewModel to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I'm trying to post the data of the viewmodel from the form to an action method on the controller, but it's always null.

This is my View:

```
@model HotelSystem.ViewModels.UpdateReservationVM

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Update Reservation";
}

<h2>Update Reservation</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Reservations", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{


<div class="form-horizontal">

    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Reservation.Guest.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Reservation.ReservationID)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ReservationID", @disabled = true } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.MiddleName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.MiddleName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Arrival", @disabled = true } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.MiddleName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @id = "Departure" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = true } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.PhoneNo, "Phone Number", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.PhoneNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.PhoneNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.MobileNo, "Mobile #", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.MobileNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.MobileNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.HomeAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.HomeAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.HomeAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.Occupation, "Occupation", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.Occupation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.Occupation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.VehiclePlateNo, "Vehicle Plate #", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reservation.VehiclePlateNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.VehiclePlateNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.TitleID, "TitleID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("TitleID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.TitleID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.CountryID, "CountryID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CountryID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.CountryID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.NationalityID, "NationalityID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("NationalityID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.NationalityID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.VIPID, "VIPID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("VIPID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.VIPID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.AgencyID, "AgencyID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("AgencyID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.AgencyID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.GroupProfileID, "GroupProfileID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("AgencyID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.GroupProfileID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.CompanyID, "Commpany", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CompanyID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.CompanyID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.GroupProfileID, "Group Profile", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("GroupProfileID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.GroupProfileID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.SourceID, "SourceID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("SourceID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.SourceID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.EmailAdd, "Email Address", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.EmailAdd, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.EmailAdd, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Room Information</label>


    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.Arrival, "Arrival", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reservation.Arrival, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Arrival, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.Departure, "Departure", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reservation.Departure, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Departure, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Nigt(s)</label>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input class="form-control" id="nights" />
         </div>
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">No. Of Room</label>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reservation.NoOfRooms, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.NoOfRooms, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.NoOfAdults, "No of Adults", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reservation.NoOfAdults, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "NoOfAdults" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.NoOfAdults, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.NoOfChild, "Child", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reservation.NoOfChild, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.NoOfChild, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Room.RoomTypeID, "RoomTypeID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.DropDownList("RoomTypeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "RoomTypeID" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Room.RoomTypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.RateID, "Rate", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.DropDownList("RateID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "RateID" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.RateID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Room.RoomID, "RoomID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.DropDownList("RoomID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Room.RoomID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.Rate, "Rate", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reservation.Rate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Rate" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Rate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.ReservationTypeID, "ReservationTypeID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ReservationTypeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.ReservationTypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.GroupProfileID, "GroupProfile", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("GroupProfileID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.GroupProfileID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.TitleID, "TitleID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("TitleID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.TitleID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.NationalityID, "NationalityID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("NationalityID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reservation.Guest.NationalityID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Payment.PaymentTypeID, "PaymentTypeID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("PaymentTypeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Payment.PaymentTypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Payment.CardID, "CardTypeID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CardTypeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Payment.CardID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Payment.BookBy, "BookBy", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("BookBy", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Payment.BookBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed transaction?');" />
            <input type="button" value="Options" class="btn btn-default" id="alert" />
            <a href="#" data-bb="alert_callback" class="btn btn-default" id="alert2">Options</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Then this is the Action Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(ViewModels.UpdateReservationVM reservation)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       db.Entry(reservation).State = EntityState.Modified;
       db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(reservation);
}
```

Then this is my View Model:

```
public class UpdateReservationVM
{
    public virtual Reservation Reservation { get; set; }

    public virtual Payment Payment { get; set; }

    public virtual FlightInfo Flight { get; set; }

    public virtual RoomReservation Room { get; set; }


    public virtual Transfer Transfer { get; set; }
}
```

What is wrong with this code? Tried to debug it, it always goes to the action method of the controller but values passed are all NULL.

Comment: modified my question, @DLeh well payment,flight,room,and transfer are null once i submit the form

Answer (score -1):

Try...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(ViewModels.UpdateReservationVM reservation)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Reservation.Attach(UpdateReservationVM.reservation);
        db.Entry(UpdateReservationVM.reservation).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(reservation);
}
```

Check to see that reservation (lowercase) is not null when debugging.

On a side note, you may want to change

```
public ActionResult Update(ViewModels.UpdateReservationVM reservation)
```

to

```
public ActionResult Update(UpdateReservationVM reservation)
```

and add a using statement at the top of your controller to include the viewmodel namespace...

```
using YOURPROJECTNAME.NAMEOFVIEWMODELSFOLDER;
```

So, in my case its

```
using salesWebsite.viewModel;
```

Answer (score -1):

Add an antiforgerytoken in your form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Reservations", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @*
        rest of code
    *@
}
```

Comment: @Luigi Vibal - if you do this, you'll also need to add [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] just below [HttpPost] in the controller.

Comment: @tintyethan still not working

Comment: Did you do what I said in my full response above? Adding the antiforgerytoken is good practice, but I don't think its related to your null form values.